# How to make BufferedWriter not overwrite a text file

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I am currently making an application where the user can add multiple accounts. The login information is being stored in a text file. I need a way for the user to add a new account without BufferedWriter overwriting the other accounts' information. Any suggestions?

```
package mainFiles.fileManagers;

import java.io.*; 


public class NewTXT {


 public static void nFile( String a , String b ) throws IOException {

     File f = new File("mainFiles\\storage\\accountinfo.txt");
     FileWriter writer = new  FileWriter("mainFiles\\storage\\accountinfo.txt"); 
     BufferedWriter bWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer); 



     f.createNewFile(); 
     f.canWrite(); 
     bWriter.newLine(); 
     bWriter.write(a + "?" + b );
     bWriter.newLine();
     bWriter.close(); 

 }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the `BufferedWriter`. You have to construct the `FileWriter` in append mode:

`FileWriter writer = new  FileWriter("mainFiles\\storage\\accountinfo.txt", true);`

Check the FileWriter documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.lang.String,%20boolean)